# How can I include .dylib files in ".json" configuration files? - VS Code on Mac iOS - Clang++ compiler - Language: c++

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, clang++, dylib

I unsuccessfully was looking 2 days on google to find a clear paragraph to describe how to include dynamic libraries (files with `.dylib` extension on Mac iOS) in order to be compiled by `clang++` when someone is setting up the **task.json** and/or **c_cpp_properties.json** files - (prior to press `F5` in order to launch the task and execute the source code)

Particularly I would like to include next two .dylib files:

1. `/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.3/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib`;
2. `/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib/libGLEW.2.2.0.dylib`;

Have to mention that I successfully succeeded to make the `clang++` to compile in the *OpenGL main.cpp* file both `glew.h` and `glfw3.h` headers as per the following snippet:

```
// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
...
```

This task was accomplished writing the next `c_cpp_properties.json` file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
              ], 
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

where the magic is done by `"macFrameworkPath"` instruction.

But yet is not enough.
I still have this error when the `clang++` compiles:

*clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*.

And this - as I understood after googling the solution - happens because is necessary to include those two dynamic libraries which I mentioned earlier.
But as I said in the beginning I didn't find how to do it.
Maybe someone can come up with a clear and appropriate solution.
My best guess is to add a new argument in `task.json` script, which by the way looks like that:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-I/Users/Armonicus/MyProjects/C++VSCodeProjects/projects/helloworld01/include",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/src/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "-Wno-deprecated",
          "-Wno-pragma-once-outside-header"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
      
      
    ]
  }
```

Best regards to all readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this particular problem is to add in `task.json` the next command arguments:

**task.json**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-I/Users/Armonicus/MyProjects/C++VSCodeProjects/projects/helloworld01/include",
          "/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.3/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib",
          "/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib/libGLEW.2.2.0.dylib",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}/src/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "-Wno-deprecated",
          "-Wno-pragma-once-outside-header"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
      
      
    ]
  }
```

As everyone can see, simply writing the full path of the file as additional argument will be accepted by compiler

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are indeed need to pass the libs into arguments of clang++.

Try to do this with -l flag, pointing to target library.

Add
`"-l /usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.3/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib"`

and

`"-l /usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.2.0_1/lib/libGLEW.2.2.0.dylib"` to the args list of strings.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that somehow ```clang++``` doesn't have access to **/usr/local** folder or at least this is what I suspect. The error is: ```ld: library not found for -l /usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.3/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```. Should I include in **task.json** a **sudo** comand or something of that sort?